# Is it possible to start an activity after refusing a call?

Tags: android, android-activity

My question is kinda simple, but as a total beginner im not able to find a way to start my activity when A phone call is refused(when the red button is pressed).
I'm looking into `startActivityForResult()` the past 30 minutes, but it seems impossible to me.

Do you have an Idea? I'm pretty sure that it can be done easily, but I'm just not able to spot the correct method.

Comment: Look into broadcast receivers for phone states. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_CALL_STATE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very likely that we can do something better than this.

I played around a bit with Eclipse and this is what I managed to do.

The MainActivity is useless. If anything, can be used for insert of a button to activate the service.

The AfterActivity is the one that is launched at the end of a call.

The heart of the app is the phoneBroadcast. In this code you can see the management of the call and the launch of the application.

Please note the uses-permission in manifest, and the android action:

```
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

for the phoneBroadcast receiver. This enables the automatic start of the receiver phoneBroadcast even after a reboot.

MainActivity.java :

```
/*
 * AfterCall - simple demo for StackOverflow
 * 2013 by Felice Murolo
 */

package com.fmtec.android.aftercall;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

AfterActivity.java :

```
package com.fmtec.android.aftercall;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class AfterActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_after);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.after, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

phoneBroadcast.java :

```
package com.fmtec.android.aftercall;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;


public class phoneBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "AfterCall-broadcastReceiver";

    public phoneBroadcast() {
        Log.d(TAG,"I'm into broadcast");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"broadcastManager Receive");
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        phoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new phoneStateListener();
        telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        Log.d(TAG,"CallState: "+telephony.getCallState());

        /* YOUR ACTIVITY WAS LAUNCHED HERE */
        if (telephony.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context,AfterActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

phoneStateListener.java :

```
package com.fmtec.android.aftercall;

import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class phoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private static final String TAG = "AfterCall-phoneStateListener";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){

        //if (incomingNumber.length()>0) Log.d(TAG, incomingNumber);

        switch(state){
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.d(TAG, "RINGING");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.d(TAG, "IDLE");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            Log.d(TAG, "OFFHOOK");
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AfterCall</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="message">Hello, I\'m the MainActivity.</string>
    <string name="message_after">Hello, I\'m the AfterActivity. I will show to you after a phonecall ending.</string>
    <string name="title_activity_after">AfterActivity</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fmtec.android.aftercall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.fmtec.android.aftercall.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.fmtec.android.aftercall.phoneBroadcast" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.fmtec.android.aftercall.AfterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_after" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml (layout MainActivity)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="@string/message"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_after.xml (layout AfterActivity)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AfterActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/message_after"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

A running service with access rights to the call state would be able to do such a thing.